# OpenMP. Parallelization of the loop in N threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to parallelize a cycle of 50 million iterations with several threads - first by 1, then by 4, 8 and 16. Below is the code for implementing this functionality.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

void someFoo();

int main() {
    someFoo();
}

void someFoo() {
    long sum = 0;
    int numOfThreads[] = {1, 4, 8, 16};
    
    for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(numOfThreads) / sizeof(int); j++) {
        omp_set_num_threads(numOfThreads[j]);
        start = omp_get_wtime();
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(int i = 0; i<50000000; i++) {
            sum += i * 10;
        }
        #pragma omp end parallel
        
        end = omp_get_wtime();
        
        cout << "Result: " << sum << ". Spent time: " << (end - start) << "\n";
    }
}
```

It is expected that in 4 threads the program will run faster than in 1, in 8 threads faster than in 4 threads, and in 16 threads faster than in 8 threads, but in practice this is not the case - everything is executed at a chaotic speed and there is almost no difference. Also, it is not visible in the task manager that the program is parallelized. I have a computer with 8 logical processors and 4 cores.

Please tell me where I made a mistake and how to properly parallelize the loop in N threads.

Answer (score 2):

There is a **race condition** in your code because `sum` is read/written from multiple threads at the same time. This should cause wrong results. You can fix this using a **reduction** with the directive `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)`. Note that OpenMP does not check if your loop can be parallelized, it is your responsibility.

Additionally, the parallel computation might be slower than the the sequential one since a clever compiler can see that `sum = 50000000*(50000000-1)/2*10 = 12499999750000000` (AFAIK, Clang does that). As a result, **the benchmark is certainly flawed**. Note that this is certainly bigger than what the type `long` can contain so there is certainly an **overflow** in your code.

Moreover, AFAIK, there is no such thing as the directive `#pragma omp end parallel`.

Finally, note that you can control the number of thread using the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable which is generally more convenient than setting it in your application (Hardwiring a given number of thread in the application code is generally not a good idea, even for benchmarks).

Comment: *AFAIK, there is no such thing as the directive #pragma omp end parallel*. Well, there is, but it's required when programming in Fortran, not C or C++.

Answer (score 2):

> Please tell me where I made a mistake and how to properly parallelize
> the loop in N threads.

First you need to fix some of the compiler issues on your code example. Like removing pragmas like `#pragma omp end parallel`, declaring the variables correctly and so on. Second you need to fix the race condition during the update of the variable `sum`. That variable is shared among threads an updated concurrently. The easiest way would be to use the `reduction` clause of OpenMP, you code would look like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
    someFoo();
}

void someFoo() {
    int numOfThreads[] = {1, 4, 8, 16};

    for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(numOfThreads) / sizeof(int); j++) {
        omp_set_num_threads(numOfThreads[j]);
        double start = omp_get_wtime();
        double sum = 0;
        #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
        for(int i = 0; i<50000000; i++) {
            sum += i * 10;
        }
        double end = omp_get_wtime();
        printf("Result: '%d' : '%f'\n", sum, (end - start));
    }
}
```

With that you should get some speedups when running with multi-cores.

**NOTE:** To solve the **overflow** mentioned first by @Jérôme Richard, I change the 'sum' variable from *long* to a *double*.

Comment: Note that if `sum` is a `double`, then the type barely provide sufficient precision for the computation to give a correct result. If works in this case on 64-bit IEEE-754 compliant machines, but if we just try `sum += 1;` at the end, then the result would be wrong. In fact, theoretically, the C++ standard does not specify sufficient requirement to make it works (the IEEE-754 standard is not a requirement of the C++ specification). `int64_t` should be safer and C++ compliant ;) .

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for the information always a pleasure to come to SO and learn from experts in the field :)